# How to reference packages generated by `dnu restore` from MSBuild?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, asp.net-core

**edit:** For those interested in getting a repro, the project is available [here](https://github.com/jamesqo/typed-xaml) on GitHub. Just `git clone` the sources, cd into the directory and run MSBuild, and (assuming you  have DNU installed) you should hit the error.

**Original Post**

I'm trying to build a "modern PCL" based on .NET Core for my upcoming library. I'm having trouble referencing the packages generated by `dnu restore` from my project. Here is the relevant portion of my `csproj` file:

```
<!-- Before building, use dnu to restore packages -->
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectJson>some\dir\project.json</ProjectJson>
    <DnuRestore>dnu restore</DnuRestore>
    <PackagesDirectory>packages</PackagesDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Exec Command="$(DnuRestore) $(ProjectJson) --packages $(PackagesDirectory)" />
</Target>
```

When I build the project from the command line via `msbuild`, the package restore seems to work, but then when I build the project they don't actually get referenced. For example, [here's](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a06344491be453fcbeab) a GitHub gist showing the output of MSBuild on the project.

As you can see from the log, the types in the dependencies aren't getting picked up by the compiler, and I'm getting a bunch of 'type not found' errors. How do I fix this?

For reference, [here's](https://github.com/jamesqo/typed-xaml/blob/master/src/Typed.Xaml/Platforms/Net45/project.json) my `project.json`:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Shims.Xaml": "1.8.0"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "net45": { }
    }
}
```

**TL;DR:** I ran `dnu restore --packages blah` from MSBuild. How do I reference the downloaded NuGet packages when compiling my library?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by simply using a wildcard glob to include all the assemblies:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="packages\**\*.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Worked like a charm.